# Wo kann man "alle zwei" sagen?

Tags: idiom

Richtig heisst es ja "alle beide", aber ich habe vielmals den Ausdruck "alle zwei" gehört, aber nur in der Umgangssprache.
Meine Frage ist: wo im deutschen Sprachraum hört man dies, und wie wird das empfunden? Als normal umgangssprachlich oder als ungebildet?

Comment: Man sagt durchaus umgangssprachlich (wohl wissend, dass das eigentlich falsch ist) "Wir zwei beide"

Comment: Warum hast du die ursprüngliche Frage gelöscht und eine neue verfasst, anstatt die ursprüngliche Frage einfach zu editieren? Ich habe nämlich auf deine ursprüngliche, fast wortgleiche Frage eine ausführliche Antwort geschrieben. Das ist eine Menge Arbeit und dauert eine gewisse Zeit. Aber kurz bevor ich damit fertig war, bekomme ich die Meldung, dass du deine Frage gelöscht hast. Und zu gelöschten Fragen kann man keine Antworten posten.

Comment: (Forts.:) Ich habe mich wirklich sehr geärgert, dass ich meine Zeit damit versch... habe dir eine Antwort zu schreiben, und habe verärgert diese Seite verlassen und mich anderen Dingen gewidmet. Und jetzt, als ich Stunden später wieder nachsehe, was es hier neues gibt, lese ich genau dieselbe Frage, die du am Vormittag gelöscht hast. Ich glaube, du hast nur zwei Wörter ausgetauscht. Jetzt bekommst du von mir keine Antwort mehr auf diese Frage, Ich mache mir sicher nicht die Arbeit, ein zweites Mal darauf einzugehen. Merke für die Zukunft: Benutze den Edit-Link wenn du etwas ändern willst!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast tut mir leid, aber dies war nicht beabsichtlicht gemacht. Ich kenne das Gefühl, wenn man mit etwas gearbeitet hat und alles plötzlich vergebens ist! Verzeihung!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Alle zwei

ist sicher nicht falsch (und meiner Meinung nach auch nicht umgangssprachlich), genauso wenig wie "alle drei" oder "alle hundert".

> Beide

ist genauso richtig und passt besser zu Dingen, die normalerweise paarweise auftreten.

> Der Hund hat beide Pantoffeln gefressen

Ich kann mir durchaus auch einen wissenschaftlichen Bericht vorstellen, der Aufzählungen in der Form

> Von den 100 Proben waren
>
> - alle zehn, die am Ort x entnommen wurden, kontaminiert
> - alle drei, die am Ort y entnommen wurden, bedenkenlos und
> - alle zwei, die in öffentlichen Parks entnommen wurden, hochbelastet

beinhaltet. In so einem Fall würde man wohl eher nicht *beide* schreiben, weil "zwei" hier als ganz normale Zahl unter vielen auftritt und nichts mit einem "Pärchen" zu tun hat.

Comment: Meinst Du mit "wissenschaftlichem Bericht" ein tatsächliches wissenschaftliches Paper oder eine Studie, oder beispielsweise einen Zeitungsartikel über eine Studie? Denn bei ersterem sehe ich eine solche Schreibweise eher nicht, unabhängig von "zwei" oder "beide".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Ich habe "wissenschaftlichen Bericht" als Beispiel im Hinblick auf "höherwertige Sprache" als Abgrenzung zu "Umgangssprache" gewählt - Such' dir aus, was deiner Meinung nach passt. Was nicht heissen soll, dass alle wissenschaftlichen Berichte unbedingt sprachlich hochwertig sein müssen...

Answer (score 1):

Hier in Südhessen werden meiner Erfahrung nach beide Versionen benutzt. "alle zwei" gilt als eher umgangssprachlich, aber ohne größeren negativen Beiklang. Den "Abstand" zwischen "alle zwei" und "alle beide" würde ich hier auch nicht so groß einschätzen.